# Split a String into 2 Strings

Tags: java, string, split, match

I am using Java and want to split a string without deleting any of the content.
Here are 2 examples,
I wish to split `String hi = "HELLO123"` into `"HELLO"` and `"123"` and I wish to split `"TEST123"` into `"TEST"` and `"123"`. Is there any java code that can do such a task? (It will always split the String between an Integer and an uppercase letter from the English language)
I tried using `.substring()` and `.split()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String s = "Hello0world";
        String[] split = s.split("(?<=[0-9]+)");
        System.out.println(split[0]);
        System.out.println(split[1]);
     }
}
```

`(?<=pattern)` Is a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It means that it'll match right after the pattern, in this case `[0-9]+` (one or more numbers).